# multiple response as a single api through springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I am having a GET mapping function with the link '/search/{id}'.I am fetching a list of couriers (List) as well as OrderRelatedInfo (Object). Is it possible to return both pieces of info through a single GET request?
Example:

```
@GetMapping("/search/{id}")
function ? search(@PathVariable String id){
courier = xyzListReturning;
Order = xyzObjectReturning;
return ?
}
```

What do I have to write at the place of '? ' Is it possible to send the courier and Order as one response?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a wrapping class like:

```
class SearchOutput {
    private Order order;
    private Courier courier;

    public SearchOutput(Order order, Courier courier) {
        this.order = order;
        this.courier = courier;
    }
    
    //getters and setters
}
```

And then use it as the return type:

```
@GetMapping("/search/{id}")
function ResponseBody<SearchOutput> search(@PathVariable String id){
    courier = xyzListReturning;
    Order = xyzObjectReturning;
        
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new SearchOutput(order, courier));
}
```